# Externalizing pspicture by nesting it into tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-external, pspicture

I'd like to externalize upwards of a thousand graphics using `pstricks` (these graphics are all internal between the body text), and decided the `external` library of the `tikz` package was the way to go. Naively I came up with code that reduces to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{external/system call={xelatex --jobname="\image" 
"\texsource"}}
\tikzset{external/optimize=false}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xargs}

\newcommandx{\NewEnvironx}[5][2,3]{%
  \expandafter\newcommandx\csname start#1\endcsname[#2][#3]{#4}%
  \NewEnviron{#1}{\csname start#1\expandafter\endcsname\BODY #5}}

\NewEnvironx{mdpicture}[1][1=]{%
    %\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pspicture}[#1]%
    }
    {%
    \end{pspicture}
    %\end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}

Some text and a picture
\ $\psset{unit=0.3cm}
\begin{mdpicture}[shift=-0.16](0,0)(1,1)
\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan,linewidth=.5pt](0,0)(0,1)(1,1)(1,0)
\psarc[linewidth=1 pt,linecolor=blue](1,0){.5}{90}{180}
\psarc[linewidth=1 pt,linecolor=blue](0,1){.5}{-90}{0}
\end{mdpicture}$\ \ and some more text.
\end{document}
```

which would then be compiled using xelatex with the shell escape option. This code works fine as it is, but uncommenting the `tikzpicture` part in the `mdpicture` environment defined above does not yield the expected behaviour: the `tikzpicture`s are not typeset and take up the whole page, and the separate `.pdf`  files generated using the procedure give errors when opening the file:

```
"The dimensions of this page are out of range. Page content might be truncated."
```

This lead me to believe that perhaps I should create a node inside the `tikzpicture` to place it at some position, e.g. with the code

```
\NewEnvironx{mdpicture}[1][1=]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) \bgroup\begin{pspicture}[#1]%
    }
    {%
    \end{pspicture}\egroup;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
```

...but this unfortunately produces the same result: a completely empty page instead of the expected (inline) `pspicture`.

Comment: You are hiding a pspicture inside a node of a tikzpicture and this inside a mdpicture which is a environ-environment. Imho it would be quite a wonder if this works. Better check the preview package and avoid all this nesting.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How would that be automated? I know how to extract graphics using the `preview` package, but replacing a thousand graphics with those extracted graphics using `pdf2ps` etc. is an insane amount of work